# Only some templates coming while creating an android studio project and the language option of java and kotlin not coming

Tags: android, android-studio

Do you know when we create a new project in android studio there  comes a template screen ?

There comes 11 templates :

1. Empty Activity
2. Basic Activity
3. Bottom Navigation Activity
4. Navigation Drawer Activity
5. Login Activity
6. Google Maps Activity
7. Tabbed Activity
8. Settings Activity
9. Master/Detail Flow
10. Fullscreen Activity
11. Scrolling Activity

But in mine there are only coming 9, even its version is latest. I'll give a photo of that.

I am a student and if anyone can help me so he/she can send the solution on my number - +91 9760679829 or email :- luckychaudhary1299@gmail.com.

I uninstalled it more than 10 times and reInstalled it. But same thing is coming. Is even it is the latest version of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is the screenshot on my side when create a new **project**.
But if I try to create a new Activity, I can get more templates.
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1, Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841, built on April 20, 2023
[image]

[image]